# Limit access specific column depending on which user is logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have created the following table for users who publish articles:

```
create_table "article", force: true do |t|
    t.boolean  "approved",          default: false
    t.string   "content",
    t.integer  "category_id",
    t.string   "title"
end
```

Now I want to limit access to one column. Regular users can edit their article fields (`content, category_id, title`) but cannot edit column `approved`. Column `approved` can be edited only by administrator.

I followed [Michael Hartl's tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=3.2) and I've done my authorization of users. I have a helper where I have method with which I can easily check is currently logged in user an administrator `logged_in_user.admin` which gives me true or false.

How can I secure the table to prevent regular users with bad intentions to change `approved` column?

Comment: If the user is not an admin, then in the update action in the controller, don't allow the approved column to be updated...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have an `article_params` method in your `ArticlesController`. Modify it as below :

```
  def article_params
    if logged_in_user.admin 
       params.require(:article).permit(:approved, :content, :category_id, :title)
    else
        params.require(:article).permit(:content, :category_id, :title)
    end
  end
```

If `logged_in_user` is `admin` only then allow `approved` attribute to be saved in database.
Make sure you permit params using `article_params` method while creating/updating an article.